# Show section header of UITableView even when it's empty

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to show the section header of my table view even when there is no object in my section.

None of these methods are called for my empty section:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

EDIT : 
I found the answer.

I was sending 0 to numberOfSectionsInTableView when I got no object that's why thoses methods wasn't call.

So even when a section is empty, my header is shown

Comment: You can write your own Answer below and accept that if it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer.

I was sending 0 to numberOfSectionsInTableView when I got no object that's why thoses methods wasn't call.

So even when a section is empty, my header is shown

Answer (score 0):

So try to put at least a placeholder object in your section. You can set a default text or information in your corresponding UITableViewCell. Or you even might set a default cell's height to a low value with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```